# Use multi-field List<> from Deserialized XML file to populate second single field list (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xml-parsing, json-deserialization

This has to be so simple... in T-SQL it would take me a second.

Before I get duplicate flags... I have been trying some similar problems posted and I have been on this for hours, tinkering with various replies involving JTokens, changing to IEnumerable, deserializing one field only to name a few. I keep getting errors such as:

> xamarin cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List to 'System.Colletions.List

I have deserialized an xml file into a list like so:

```
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(LoadResourceText)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("papapp.WineCatInfo.xml");

        List<WineCategoryInfo> winecategoryinfos;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<WineCategoryInfo>));
            winecategoryinfos = (List<WineCategoryInfo>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        #endregion

        return winecategoryinfos;
```

The list it populates is defined like so:

```
public class WineCategoryInfo
    {
        public string WineTypeNo { get; set; }
        public string WineFamily { get; set; }
        public string MainStyle { get; set; }
        public string StyleType { get; set; }
        public string LengthCharacteristic { get; set; }
        public string RegionCommonAppelation { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like a query on the deserialized date to place all the values of one particular field from the above list into a second list, defined like so:

```
public class WineFamilies
    {    
        public string WineFamily { get; set; }    
    }
```

Can someone explain to me how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [LINQ](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

```
using System.Linq;

var family = (from x in winecategoryinfos select x.WineFamily).ToList<string>();
```

or to eliminate duplicates

```
var family = (from x in winecategoryinfos select x.WineFamily).Distinct().ToList<string>();
```

if you want to use your WineFamilies class instead of string, try

```
var family = (from x in winecategoryinfos select new WineFamilies() { WineFamily = x.WineFamily }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason, But this does not work for me for some reason. I'm sooo glad you replied that as I had tried that and could not see what the prob was.  Inserting your suggestion exactly, typing "return family;"  in a "public class List<WineFamilies> winefamilies()" gives me the dreaded "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List<pappapp.WineFamilies>'

Comment: see my additional example

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working, the resulting array is populated purely with lines of "papapp.Winefamilies". So if I put this in the picker: BindingContext = new TodoListPageViewModel WinecatList = GetWineInfo() }; All I get is "papapp.WineFamilies" throughout the picker.

Comment: that is most likely a problem with how your Picker bindings are setup, and has nothing to do with how you're generating the data

Comment: Picker has a ItemDisplayBinding property that you can use to specify which property to display.  If you don't use this, it will just call ToString() on the class, which by default returns the name of the class

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh..... I think my last 8 hours may have been more productive knowing that.... I'll check. Thank you so much Jason.

Comment: Actually... @Jason, are you sure your code is returning a list with just one field? I have tried sticking a distinct in there as in : var family = (from x in winecategoryinfos select new WineFamilies() { WineFamily = x.WineFamily }).Distinct().ToList(); and am getting a ton of duplicates....

Comment: DIstinct won't on custom data types unless you provide comparison operators.  That said, is there really a reason you need a custom WineFamily class when it only contains a single property?

Comment: Gottit:                                                                               
                                                                                         
List<WineCategoryInfo> distinctfamilies = winecategoryinfos.GroupBy(x => x.WineFamily).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
            var family = (from x in distinctfamilies select new WineFamilies() { WineFamily = x.WineFamily }).ToList();